# wxPython - How can I display a html formatted string in wx.RichTextCtrl

Tags: wxpython, richtextctrl

I'm trying to display some string (html formatted) in a Richtext Ctrl. In my code I tried to use it this way (self.txtmain is the RichTextCtrl):

```
out = StringIO()
htmlhandler = rt.RichTextHTMLHandler()
buffer = self.txtmain.GetBuffer()
buffer.AddHandler(htmlhandler)
out.write(string)
out.seek(0)
htmlhandler.LoadStream(buffer, out)
self.txtmain.Refresh()
```

No errors are issued, but the RichTextCtrl windows is not updated. 
What am I missing here?

Comment: check result of `htmlhandler.LoadStream(buffer, out)`, false means it failed (not that I knew why, still working on that)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in "wx.Layout()", to update window/widget.

In certain cases i use "wx.Layout()" to redraw entire window, after add an item

for example, when i hide one and show another widget in same place...

in this case, self.Layout(), after self.txtmain.Refresh()..

```
out = StringIO()
htmlhandler = rt.RichTextHTMLHandler()
buffer = self.txtmain.GetBuffer()
buffer.AddHandler(htmlhandler)
out.write(string)
out.seek(0)
htmlhandler.LoadStream(buffer, out)
self.txtmain.Refresh()
self.Layout()
```

But, i not sure  it'd  work in you case...

and to retrieve a content from a StringIO() must use getvalue()

```
htmlhandler.LoadStream(buffer, out)
```

to

```
  htmlhandler.LoadStream(buffer, out.getvalue())
```

Comment: Changed to out.getvalue() but I have now "TypeError: Expected wx.InputStream or Python file-like object."